# Matplotlib pcolor memory leak

Tags: python, memory, memory-leaks, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a matrix assign to each element a color based on its value. I used pcolor() from Matplotlib.pyplot library (coding in Python):

```
plt.figure()
plt.pcolor(matrix,cmap=my_cmap)
plt.colorbar()
plt.savefig("Matrix.png")
```

I tested with a 5000 x 5000 matrix but I had serious memory leak problems. As I found on some forums I updated to the newest version of matplotlib but I still have the problem. I ran it on a cluster setting 80GB of memory but these are not enough!! Suggestions on how can I resolve this memory leak?

Comment: What do you mean 'memory leak'?  Using more memory than you expect does not mean it has a leak, just that it uses more than you expect.

Comment: But I think that using more than 80GB to plot a 5000x5000 matrix is not something normal!

Comment: `pcolor` draws a separate polygon for every cell, and therefore has rather excessive memory usage. It's not intended for large regular grids (it supports triangular cells, etc).  Use `pcolormesh` instead if you want vector output or `imshow` if you want a colored image. `pcolormesh` is intended for large regular grids, but still produces vector output like `pcolor`.  `imshow` is much more efficient than either, but will produce a image, rather than vector output.

Comment: @JoeKington - I'd suggest that was a good answer to the question...